# Auto mounted disk not allowing to create virtualenv

Tags: python, fstab, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have a auto mounted rive which is allowed to access by two users. These are the rules in my `/etc/fstab`

```
#user1
UUID=123FSDF345233 /media/user1/Disk ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,sync,auto,rw 0 0 

#user2
UUID=123FSDF345233 /media/user1/Disk ntfs uid=1001,gid=1002,umask=000,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

I allows me to create,view and write files and folders. But When I tried to create a virtualenv using `virtualenv env` its giving this error

> OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/media/user1/Disk/.Env/env/env/bin/python'

This error only happens in this drive. I also tried the same command in a different drive also where it worked. I also tried to change the permission using

```
sudo chmod ugo+wx /media/user1/Disk
```

But still getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested I solved my problem by removing both out

```
#user1
UUID=123FSDF345233 /media/user1/Disk ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,sync,auto,rw 0 0 

#user2
UUID=123FSDF345233 /media/user1/Disk ntfs uid=1001,gid=1002,umask=000,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

and replacing those with a single command in `/etc/fstab` where sdb6 is our drive with `UUID=123FSDF345233`

```
dev/sdb6 /media/user1/Disk ntfs auto
```